# Grouping data by change in another column

Tags: r, tidyverse

Given a data frame like this:

```
station <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2)
obs <- c(12.3, 10.4, 9.8, 15.9, 8.2, 8.4, 6.3, 10.2, 9.0, 8.3)
df <- data.frame(station, obs)
```

I would like to create a new column `run` like so:

```
   station  obs run
1        1 12.3   1
2        2 10.4   1
3        3  9.8   1
4        1 15.9   2
5        2  8.2   2
6        3  8.4   2
7        1  6.3   3
8        2 10.2   3
9        2  9.0   4
10       2  8.3   5
```

If I were to write this in a different language, my pseudo-code would look something like this:

```
run := 1
if station(previous) >= station(current):
  run := run + 1
```

How do I do this in R with `tidyr` and friends?

Comment: where are you getting ``temp`` from? Do you mean `obs`? Also, please explain in words what you need, not in "pseudo-code"...

Comment: @RichScriven yes, I meant `dplyr`.  As for the cut and paste fail, someone else fixed it before I could -- thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(run = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(station)<=0)))
```

> ```
>    station  obs run
> 1        1 12.3   1
> 2        2 10.4   1
> 3        3  9.8   1
> 4        1 15.9   2
> 5        2  8.2   2
> 6        3  8.4   2
> 7        1  6.3   3
> 8        2 10.2   3
> 9        2  9.0   4
> 10       2  8.3   5
> ```